# In R, is there danger of communication between foreach loops (doSNOW) when using assignments to store intermediate output?

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing, parallel-foreach

I want to create a function that uses assignments to store intermediate output (p). This intermediate output is used in statements below. I want everything to be parallelized using doSNOW and foreach and I do NOT want that intermediate output to be communicated between iteration of the forearch loop. I don't want to store intermediate output in a list (e.g. `p[[i]]`) because then I have to change a huge amount of code.

- **Question 1:** Is there any danger that another iteration of the foreach loop will use the intermediate output (p)?
- **Question 2:** If yes, when would there be danger of that happening and how to prevent it?

Here is an example of what I mean:

```
install.packages('foreach')
library('foreach')

install.packages('doSNOW')
library('doSNOW')

NbrCores <- 4
cl<-makeCluster(NbrCores) 
registerDoSNOW(cl)

test <- function(value){
   foreach(i=1:500) %dopar% {
      #some statement based on parameter 'value'
      p <- value
      #some statement that uses p
      v <- p
      #other statements
  }
}

test(value=1)
```

Comment: Usually the request is the opposite, to establish some sort of communication, which is hard because isolation of results is usually enforced.

Comment: @DWin that is indeed often the request. Just to be clear; I want no communication at all.

Comment: I don't think there is any danger. The cpu-process should not share memory and R does not change variables in-place, anyway. If you want other more informed opinions, the right place to pose the question is the R High Performance Computing SIG mailing list.

Answer (score 0):

Each of the nodes used in parallel computations runs in its own R process I believe. Therefore there is no risk of variables from one node influencing the results in another. In general, there is a possibility to communicate between the processes. However foreach only iterates over the sequence it is given, executing each item in the sequence in one of the nodes independently.